# How to retrieve database table value in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to the Hibernate, i want to retrieve table values from database, I have a code but it returns object values. My sample code is,

```
Configuration conf=new Configuration();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SessionFactory sessionfactory=conf.configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session session=sessionfactory.openSession();
    List maintable = null;
    try
    {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery ("select main.empid,main.address from Main as main");
         maintable =q.list();
         Object[] obj=maintable.toArray();

          for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
          {
              System.out.println("column valuse : "+obj[i]);

          }

    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
```

I need to get multiple column values...How can i do that?

Comment: I'm also new to Hibernate but from what I understand, this is the intention. You want to be able to manipulate objects and not worry about the table itself.

Comment: What you mean by object value? will you elaborate it?

Comment: @PSK As per my understanding you should get `Object[][]` (two dimensional Object array) instead of `Object[]`. Can you check `maintable` for this after doing `q.list()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can retrieve value from list easily.But in my above question i print only object property not a value.

```
Query qry=session.createQuery("from Main");
    List<Main> user=(List<Main>) qry.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
    for(Main u : user)
    {
        System.out.println("User id : "+u.getEmpid());
        System.out.println("User Address:"+u.getAddress());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what Hibernate (or JPA rather) is meant for. If you want to access regular values, use JDBC instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
select main.empid,main.address from Main as main
```

please check that `empid,address` are the column name in the database or the property name of Main class.

It should be the property name of entity(i.e Main) class.

Comment: s, empid,address is a column name of table, if i put this "select main.empid,main.address from Main as main" query in my hql editor means it gives the output. But i want to know, how to retrieve value via list to display table values in console, my coding displays answer"[Ljava.lang.Object;@169b35 bla bla..
" like this

Comment: May I look your Main class, so that I can give you proper solution

Comment: i can retrieve value if i put "select main.empid from Main as main" or "select main.address from Main as main" in creatquery statement of my program. I save the values in list. I retrieve value using for loop, but it displays different value..

Comment: thak u @Ashish i got answer

Answer (score 0):

It’s very useful when we retrieve some fields/properties from our entity class. The above query with “new” keyword can return a list of type “Main”. If we do not use such a keyword and specify the fields directly, a list of type Object [ ] is retrieved.

`select new Main(main.empid,main.address) from Main as main` ,

Comment: I need to print multiple column values in console...How can i do that?

Comment: Query q = session.createQuery ("select new Main(main.empid,main.address) from Main as main"); List<Main> main=q.list(); try this

Comment: Here `Main` returns single dimensional array. But i need to retrieve values from multiple columns.I can not retrieve it..

Comment: add your solution here so that it will help someone in future.

Comment: I can retrieve value from list easily.But in my above question i print only object property not a value.`Query qry=session.createQuery("from Main");
    List<Main> user=(List<Main>) qry.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
    for(Main u : user)
    {
        System.out.println("User id : "+u.getEmpid());
        System.out.println("User Address:"+u.getAddress());
    }`